# How get last frame of rendering in camera

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, rendering

How get last frame of rendering in camera (Unity3d)? I have many gameobjects in scene and I want when scene is not changed show texture in camera instead all gameobjects.

Comment: I am reading your question 2 minutes now, and I dont know what do you really want. Can you try editing your question so we know what exactly is the problem? Right now I doubt anyone will help you, unless he will quess correct what is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Monobehaviour has one special function - [OnPostRender()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnPostRender.html) - that is called after every frame camera renders. Another thing you should dig into is the screen capturing example in the documentation of [WaitForEndOfFrame()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForEndOfFrame.html).

Comment: OnPostRender has a frame lag with two cameras FYI